# Problem trying to upgrade 10.04 to 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 10.04, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

I am trying to upgrade from10.04 to 12.04.

While setting new software channels I get the following errors:

W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/karmic/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
...............................
seven more errors of this type 
...............................
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

and the upgrading process is stopped.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as you're using a **Karmic Koala** (9.10) repository. As Karmic isn't supported anymore, your system can't be updated.

If you're using 10.04, try disabling those repositories. For further info, could you please attach your sources.list file? Use this command and paste the output:

> cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
added by the release upgrader
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala - Release i386 (20091027)]/ karmic main restricted
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 8.10 Intrepid Ibex - Release i386 (20081030)]/ intrepid main restricted
See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
newer versions of the distribution.

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid main restricted
Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
distribution.

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates main restricted
N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid universe deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates universe
deb http://cran.opensourceresources.org/bin/linux/ubuntu jaunty/ # disabled on upgrade to karmic
N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
security team.

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
Uncomment the following two lines to add software from the 'backports'
repository.
N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ intrepid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
'partner' repository. This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is
offered by Canonical and the respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu
users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu intrepid partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu intrepid partner
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/dell-team/ubuntu jaunty main # disabled on upgrade to jaunty
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/dell-team/ubuntu jaunty main # disabled on upgrade to jaunty
deb http://kondr.ic.cz/deb lucid main # disabled on upgrade to karmic
deb http://kondr.ic.cz/deb lucid main # disabled on upgrade to karmic

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-proposed restricted main multiverse universe deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-backports restricted main multiverse universe deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security restricted main multiverse universe deb http://kondr.ic.cz/deb lucid main deb http://cran.stat.unipd.it/bin/linux/ubuntu lucid/
```

Comment: Methinks, a dodgy upgrade from karmic?

Comment: How to disable those repositories? In the sources.list all karmic lines are beginning with #, for some reason it is not visible here in this pasted text.